# Value getting reset in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I'm working on a new react native app and there's going to be a lot of things in the app that are a sequence of screens that I want to show one after the other in a specific order. To control this, I'd like to make a hook that provides a way of declaring my sequence of screens, and then being able to move forward or backward one at a time. So you could use it something like this:

```js
const screenSeq = useScreenSeq(Screen1, Screen2, Screen3);
const Screen = screenSeq.curr

React.useEffect() => {
  screenSeq.start(someProps);
}, []);

return (
  <View>
    <Button onclick={() => screenSeq.next(newProps)}>Next</Button>
    <Button onclick={() => screenSeq.prev(newProps)}>Prev</Button>
    <Screen />;
  </View>
);
```

And then when you click the buttons, it cycles through the screens. I've got something that looks kinda like this:

```js
export default (...screens) => {
  let [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  let [props, setProps] = React.useState([]);

  return  {
    start: (props) => setProps(props),
    curr: () => screens[index](props),
    next: (props) => {
      if (index < screens.length-1) {
        setIndex(index + 1);
        setProps(props);
      }
    },
    prev: (props) => {
      if (index > 0) {
        setIndex(index - 1);
        setProps(props);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So you initialize your starting props using the `start` function, and then call `next` or `prev` with the props for the respective screen.

At the moment, the first time I click the `Next` button, it goes to the next screen successfully, but then after that it won't continue. When I inspect what's going on, the index is constantly getting reset back to 0 and just incremented back to 1, so it always stays on the second screen. Anyone might know what's going on? Can anyone point out what my mistake is to get it to increment and decrement successfully on every button click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this occurs it is either because you are working with stale enclosures of state or the function as a whole is entirely redeclared.

I think in your case it is the former. To resolve stale state state enclosures you, and especially when incrementing/decrementing counts/values/etc, you should use a functional state update to correctly update from the previous state versus whatever state value is closed over in callback scope.

```
next: (props) => {
  if (index < screens.length-1) {
    setIndex(index => index + 1); // <-- update from previous state
    setProps(props);
  }
},
prev: (props) => {
  if (index > 0) {
    setIndex(index => index - 1); // <-- update from previous state
    setProps(props);
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay, well this seems a little bit like magic, but it works! I've never seen this before, very cool.

Comment: @nixin72 It's totally black magic   [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

Answer (score 0):

When you click next/prev - your component gets re-rendered and a new copy of `useScreenSeq` is created every render.
And as we can see the in the code of `useScreenSeq` the default index is 0, so now you can understand why it gets reset to 0 again and again.

To overcome this you can use the `useCallback` hook to avoid creation of new copies of `useScreenSeq` on every re-render.